# Efficient way of splitting/removing specific string

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have the following string example:

```
[14:48:51.690] LOGON           error group: 103
```

I get many different from them. The only thing is, that the beginning is always the same expect the date (always in brackets) and name of `LOGON`. I want to remove thi in front. 
How can I achieve this efficiently? Regex? Splitting and remove from array?

The only thing I want to have finally is

```
error group: 103
```

Comment: Does it always start after a certain number of characters. If so you can just use `line.substring(n)`.

Comment: @aioobe No. The date can just have for example this format [1:1:22.333] and the word LOGON can differ.

Comment: Is there always exactly one "event" word after the date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the string based on regex `\[\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\.\d{1,3}\]\s*\w*\s*`

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class T {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "[14:48:51.690] LOGON           error group: 103";

        String[] split = s.split("\\[\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{1,3}\\]\\s*\\w*\\s*");

        System.out.println(split[1]);
    }
}
```

Output

```
error group: 103
```

Comment: But this would only work, if the date is exactly [2numbers:2numbers:2numbers.3numbers]

Comment: @MarcelHöll no because of `d{1,2}`

Comment: @adam.kubi wait what? oh! it could be either 1 digit or 2 digits based on d{1,2) and 1 to 3 digits based on d{1,3}.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using a simple regular expression:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[.*\\]\\s*LOGON\\s*(.*)\\s*");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("[14:48:51.690] LOGON           error group: 103");
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));           
    }
```

So essentially we scan the opening bracket, the date inside it, the closing bracket, any whitespace
in between until and capture the part you're looking for using `(.*)`.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is a very expensive task. If you're searching into a log file with 100,000 lines, it will take too much time! If your string always has the same pattern, TRY TO TAKE ADVANTAGE OF IT!

I'm assuming your line is:

```
[some_time] some_event         some event description
```

Simplest way I can see now is just to search for the second space and get everything after it.

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){

        String s = "[14:48:51.690] LOGON           error group: 103";
        int pos = getPosOfFirstAlphaNumericCharAfterSecondSpace(s);
        if (pos > 0)
            System.out.println(s.substring(pos));
     }

     private static int getPosOfFirstAlphaNumericCharAfterSecondSpace(String s) {
         int countSpaces = 0;
         for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == ' ')
                countSpaces++;
            else if (countSpaces >= 2)
                return i;
         }
         return -1;

     }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Regex is indeed expensive, harder to read and decode later, easier to get wrong, and often needlessly overused.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the event text ("LOGIN" in your case) is all caps and one word:

```
String target = str.replaceAll(".*?\\]\\s*[A-Z]+\\s*", "");
```

Comment: This does not work on my machine if `str` points to this `"[14:48:51.690] LOGON           error group: 103";` and the `target` variable is printed out with an SOP.

Comment: @user_loser I had a typo (left out a "*"). I have fixed the answer (and tested it and it works). Merry Xmas!